# Is there a way to save data in named Excel cells using Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have used openpyxl for outputting values in Excel in my Python code. However, now I find myself in a situation where the cell locations in excel file may change based on the user. To avoid any problems with the program, I want to name the cells where the code can save the output to. Is there any way to have Python interact with named ranges in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a workbook level defined name

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("c:/tmp/SO/namerange.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

mycell = wb.defined_names['mycell']

for title, coord in mycell.destinations:
    ws = wb[title]
    ws[coord] = "Update"    

wb.save('updated.xlsx')
print("{} {} updated".format(ws,coord))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the parameters of the named range using defined_names. After that I just worked like it was a normal Excel cell.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

openWB=load_workbook('test.xlsx')

rangeDestination = openWB.defined_names['testCell']
print(rangeDestination)
sheetName=str(rangeDestination.attr_text).split('!')[0]
cellName = str(rangeDestination.attr_text).split('!')[1]

sheetToWrite=openWB[sheetName]
cellToWrite=sheetToWrite[cellName]
sheetToWrite[cellName]='TEST-A3'
print(sheetName)
print(cellName)

openWB.save('test.xlsx')
openWB.close()
```